# Android: Highlight search query in results like Apple's notes.app

Tags: android

I am new to Android. I use an iPhone, so I am not just new to the programming, but also to the OS completely. I just started this week and have written a basic notes application.

Now, when I go to the search view, search say "cats", if a result appears and I click to go to that note, I want all instances of "cats" to be highlighted. Then, when I tap in the EditText, I want the highlighting to go away.

It would also be awesome if I could highlight the text within the search view.

Apple's Notes.app does this and I think it really adds to the search functionality. Couldn't find any images to show you what I mean. Hopefully I explained it well enough.

I tried this:

```
    //highlight searched text

    //Get the text of the EditText
    String text = editText.getText().toString();

    //Get indexes of the query in the EditText
    int firstIndex = text.indexOf(query);
    int lastIndex = text.lastIndexOf(query);

    //Highlight the selection
    editText.setSelection(firstIndex, lastIndex);
```

But we run into problems if there are multiple of the same word. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some googling and looked searching "java" instead of "android" was helpful. Below is my working code:

```
private void highlightIndexes(String query){
    String text = editText.getText().toString();
    Map<Integer, Integer> indexMap = getIndexes(query);
    Spannable spannable=new SpannableString(text);

    Iterator<Integer> keySetIterator = indexMap.keySet().iterator();

    while(keySetIterator.hasNext()){
        Integer key = keySetIterator.next();
        Integer value = indexMap.get(key);
        spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), key, value, 0);
    }

    editText.setText(spannable);

}

private Map<Integer, Integer> getIndexes(String query){
    Map<Integer, Integer> indexMap = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
    int queryLength = query.length();
    query = query.substring(0, (queryLength -1)).toLowerCase(Locale.US);
    String text = editText.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.US);
    int i, y;

    i = text.indexOf(query);
    y = i + queryLength - 1;
    indexMap.put(i, y);

    while(i >= 0) {
         i = text.indexOf(query, i+1);
         y = i + queryLength - 1;

         if (i != -1 && y != -1){
             indexMap.put(i, y);
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

*Selection* and *highlighting* are not the same thing. Usually, selecting something also highlights it, but you don't highlight something by selecting it. Besides, Android does not support multiple selection in `EditText`.

To highlight, you need to apply a `CharacterStyle` to the range of text, such as a `BackgroundColorSpan`.

[This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/RichText/Search) applies a `BackgroundColorSpan` to highlight search results in a `TextView`, using:

```
  private void searchFor(String text) {
    TextView prose=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.prose);
    Spannable raw=new SpannableString(prose.getText());
    BackgroundColorSpan[] spans=raw.getSpans(0,
                                             raw.length(),
                                             BackgroundColorSpan.class);

    for (BackgroundColorSpan span : spans) {
      raw.removeSpan(span);
    }

    int index=TextUtils.indexOf(raw, text);

    while (index >= 0) {
      raw.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFF8B008B), index, index
          + text.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
      index=TextUtils.indexOf(raw, text, index + text.length());
    }

    prose.setText(raw);
  }
```

The code shown first removes any existing `BackgroundColorSpan` instances, then applies new ones based on a search string.

Since `EditText` inherits from `TextView`, the same basic concept would apply here. However, IMHO, doing this sort of highlighting in an `EditText` will be foreign to users. I'd show the search results in a plain `TextView`, with an "edit" action bar item or something to move into editing mode.

Comment: I figured out my own problem in a similar manner. I will post the code below. 

I like your comment about entering into a plain TextView at first. I have been annoyed at how hard it is to read the notes when every time I click, it wants to edit. Is there an editable flag on EditText or will I just need to add another element to the page?

Comment: @Brandon: "Is there an editable flag on EditText" -- not really.

Comment: @Brandon: Yes, but my understanding is that it doesn't work very well across devices, though it has been quite some time since I heard any complaints about it.

Comment: It's also deprecated. Eclipse just told me to use android:inputType="none" instead. 

I'm going to try it. It just seems easier to toggle that in code instead of creating a textView on top of the editView and trying to toggle those in code.